# In Julia, when i using CSVread or readtable , ther error " xx not defined" show

Tags: csv, julia

In Julia, when i using  CSVread ,the error show as image ,anyone can help?

```
using DataFrames
using CSV
data = CSVread("total_0.csv")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `CSV.read("total_0.csv", DataFrame)`

Comment: Thanks, The code [data = CSV.read("total_0.csv",DataFrame) ] can run and no error message .  but the result data is empty

Comment: so probably the CSV file is empty?

Comment: the file size is very huge (more than 3M rows), after using little size for testing ,the code ok.  Is there another way for big file ? Thanks!

Comment: What you use should be efficient for big files, unless it does not fit in RAM, but 3M rows is not much so it should fit without a problem.